# Red light, no green light, SD works on other Pi

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, sd-card

Raspberry Pi 3B+, only 10 days old, running latest Raspbian and kernel. Mainly connected to TV via HDMI.

Suddenly turns off today, and can’t be revived.

Constant red light, no green light.

Tried a different SD card with the same Pi, power supply and HDMI - same symptoms.

Tried the original SD card with a different Pi 3B with the same power supply and HDMI — no problems at all.

After searching the FAQs and guides — seems the Raspberry Pi 3B+ is toast?

Comment: It's a long shot, but the USB power connection might be intermittent and trigger-happy.

Comment: Is this on-board? I tried with an alternative power supply and no luck.

Answer (score 4):

## Here are some ways to revive an RPi

---

#### Try the pin method

sometimes the SD-card reader on the pi gets deformed over time, so applying some pressure on the SD-card with a pin or folded paper could work, also cleaning it with a brush works sometimes. refer to [this](https://www.element14.com/community/message/205895/l/re-my-lovely-raspberrypi-is-dead#205895) for further explanation

[image: how a deformed SD-card looks]

---

#### You could try booting from a USB

*(assuming your USB ports are in a good shape)*

Flash a USB disk or you can just insert your SD-card into a USB SD-card reader
Since you are using an RPi-3b+ you only need to write 
`program_usb_boot_mode=1`
In **config.txt** then try booting.
 **If it doesn't work (USB disk doesn't get powered)** then measure the voltage between `PP-2 and PP-27` or `PP-7 and PP-27` ideally it should be around `5V` if it isn't then you could connect PP-2 and PP-27 like this [over here](https://youtu.be/c0lb3NVKcDE) or you could replace `C97` and `U13` like done over [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=110164#p776772).

*or*

**if USB does get powered but you can't boot** then either

*the Device is not supported* or
*the Device takes longer than 2 seconds to power up or respond.*

Here are some supported USB Drives

- Sandisk Cruzer Fit 16GB
- Sandisk Cruzer Blade 16Gb
- Samsung 32GB USB 3.0 drive
- MeCo 16GB USB 3.0

If you are not using one of these, there is still a good chance that your USB drive is supported.

---

#### If all fails

If Nothing works then probably your RPi is RIP, if it is really dead then it will not read any 'Mass Storage Device' give any HDMI output, and have a **cold Soc**, some 5V GPIO sources may work, like for a fan.

If your pi isn't cold then there is some CPU activity but no storage to read so in this case you should replace the SD-card slot or USB slots however it's risky and might damage your pi, though it is worth a try since a working pi is better than a dead one.

---

### Conclusion

You must remember that an RPi is a small computer the size of a credit card for $35 not some super-expensive gaming rig if it is dead then toss into a bin or replace it. Don't waste your time tinkering with an expensive red LED.

---

Hope this helps!